# How to deep copy 2 dimensional array (different row sizes)

Tags: java, arrays, deep-copy, dimension

This is my first question in a community like this, so my format in question may not be very good sorry for that in the first place.

Now that my problem is I want to deep copy a 2 dimension array in Java. It is pretty easy when doin it in 1 dimension or even 2 dimension array with fixed size of rows and columns. My main problem is I cannot make an initialization for the second array I try to copy such as:

```
int[][] copyArray = new int[row][column]
```

Because the row size is not fixed and changes in each row index such as I try to copy this array:

```
int[][] envoriment = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 6}, {1}};
```

So you see, if I say `new int[3][4]` there will be extra spaces which I don't want. Is there a method to deep copy such kind of 2 dimensional array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what you mean is that the column size isn't fixed. Anyway a simple straightforward way would be:

```
public int[][] copy(int[][] input) {
      int[][] target = new int[input.length][];
      for (int i=0; i <input.length; i++) {
        target[i] = Arrays.copyOf(input[i], input[i].length);
      }
      return target;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I seek in general. Thanks for all of the answers they all helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to initialize both dimensions at the same time:

```
int[][] test = new int[100][];
test[0] = new int[50];
```

Does it help ?

Comment: Oh this information will help. I never thought of initializing dimensions in different time

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 lambdas make this easy:

```
int[][] copy = Arrays.stream(envoriment).map(x -> x.clone()).toArray(int[][]::new);
```

You can also write `.map(int[]::clone)` after [JDK-8056051](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8056051) is fixed, if you think that's clearer.

Answer (score -2):

You might need something like this:

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] envoriment = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 6}, {1}};

    int[][] copyArray = new int[envoriment.length][];
    System.arraycopy(envoriment, 0, copyArray, 0, envoriment.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you are proposing is shallow-copying, isn't it? The arraycopy will copy each value of the environment array into the new one. It is: it will copy the references to the original rows. It's not going to copy the sub-arrays.

Comment: @rlibby and @Helios, are you guys sure it does shallow copy? I thought is does a deep copy. In that case let me revisit. I might be wrong. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: it is shallow copy, you are copying references to one dimensional arrays, you can check by  adding this after your code: envoriment[2][0] = 5; and check copyArray[2][0] is now also 5