# Java array cloning strange behavior

Tags: java, arrays, clone

I'm trying to clone an instance of a custom class I made called CSP. I have one instance called csp and I want to make a clone of csp called cspclone. Here is what I'm using to do that:

`CSP cspclone = new CSP((csp.x).clone(), (csp.d).clone(), (csp.c).clone());`

For some reason though when I pass cspclone to a method that modifies it csp gets modified also as if I forgot the .clone() functions but I didn't! Why is this happening?!

Comment: `.clone()` only performs a shallow copy of your object, so references to the fields in csp are being copied into cspclone.

Comment: So what's the easiest way to make real copies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `clone` method in `CSP`:

```
public class CSP {
    private String aField;
    private int[] array;
    private int[][] twoDArr;
    private List<ALContent> list; //here ALContent also needs to override clone properly

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        CSP clone = new CSP();
        clone.aField = this.aField;
        clone.array = new int[this.array.length];
        System.arraycopy(this.array, 0, clone.array, 0, this.array.length);

        clone.list = new ArrayList<ALContent>();
        for(ALContent content : this.list) {
            clone.list.add(content.clone()); //make sure you add the clone of the content
        }

        clone.twoDArr = new int[this.twoDArr.length][];
        for(int i=0; i<this.twoDArr.length; i++) {
            clone.twoDArr[i] = new int[this.twoDArr[i].length];
            System.arraycopy(this.twoDArr[i], 0, clone.twoDArr[i], 0, this.twoDArr[i].length);
        }

        return clone;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
CSP csp = new CSP();
CSP cspClone = (CSP) csp.clone();
```

Comment: So what goes where the `//...` is?

Comment: Ok, so how would I do it for non-arrays? Here are the fields of a CSP object: 
`public int[] x;
public ArrayList<String> d[];
public int[][] c;`

Comment: The default implementation of the `clone` in `ArrayList` does shallow copy: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clone%28%29. So, you have to do it manully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents.

Comment: @StickFigs: Updated the answer again.

Comment: @StickFigs: For int[][], check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563157/how-to-deep-copy-2-dimensional-array-different-row-sizes

Comment: @StickFigs: See the update for the 2 dimensional array int[][].

Answer (score 0):

If your properties of array type use [System.arraycopy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29

> this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

You might have to *override* the clone method and `clone()` a *reference type* attribute within the object (i.e., perform deep copy operation).

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you need deep cloning. The default clone method does a shallow copy. See [Object.clone()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29).

Here are some approaches. All have advantages and drawbacks.

- Override: Override the clone() method.
- Serialization: Write the object to a stream and a read it back from the stream.
- Reflection: Here is a [tutorial on reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).
- Use a deep close library, such as [Java Deep-Cloning library](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/).

Here are several other stackoverflow discussions of cloning.

- [Java: recommended solution for deep cloning/copying an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156120/java-recommended-solution-for-deep-cloning-copying-an-instance)
- [Deep clone utility recomendation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/665860/1007364)
- [How to clone ArrayList and also clone its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715650/how-to-clone-arraylist-and-also-clone-its-contents)