# Copying a 2D array using .clone() still references original data

Tags: java, arrays, copy, clone

Okay, I know this question has been asked before: [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8287629/921224)

I have also looked into a few other threads and websites and they all seem to create more questions than answers.

[Josh Bloch on Design](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) - an article discussing `.clone();`

But I still couldn't work out the answer to my problem.

When I clone my 2D array:

```
values = Map.mapValues.clone();
```

I still cannot safely modify the content of `values` as it still modifies the content of `Map.mapValues`.

Is there actually a way to copy an array which is more efficient than me just re-creating one from scratch each time?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, a 2D array is an array of references to 1D arrays. `Map.mapValues.clone()` only clones the first layer (i.e. the references), so you end up with a new array of references to **the same underlying 1D arrays**. This is why your attempt to use `clone()` did not work.

One way to fix this is by also cloning the underlying 1D arrays:

```
byte[][] values = Map.mapValues.clone();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  values[i] = values[i].clone();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixes my problem, is there a different method I could call which doesn't involve using a for(;;) loop?

Comment: @SebastianTroy: I don't know of any function in the standard library that would do this. I personally would turn the four lines of code into a helper function that can be invoked as needed.

Comment: Hi, I've been cleaning up my old questions, tried to keep your answer valid, just in case you wanted to check...