# Copying array contents to a new array

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I am trying to write a method called reallocate, which takes an array called theDirectory, and copies it's contents over into a new array named newDirectory, which has twice the capacity. Then theDirectory is set to newDirectory.

This is what I have so far, however I am stuck on how to copy content across to newDirectory, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
private void reallocate()
   {
       capacity = capacity * 2;
       DirectoryEntry[] newDirectory = new DirectoryEntry[capacity];
       //copy contents of theDirectory to newDirectory
       theDirectory = newDirectory;

   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299771/copying-an-array-using-clone-original-array-being-changed?rq=1

Comment: Please accept an answer if it solved your problem or rephrase your question if you need further help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.arrayCopy` for that.

API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

Simple example with destination array with double capacity:

```
int[] first = {1,2,3};
int[] second = {4,5,6,0,0,0};
System.arraycopy(first, 0, second, first.length, first.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(second));
```

**Output**

```
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the elements of the old array, and assign each to the corresponding position in the new array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)`(theDirectory, 0, newDirectory, 0, theDirectory.length)`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at System.arraycopy() :)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int)

Should just be something like

```
System.arraycopy(oldArray, 0, newArray, 0, oldArray.size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [java.util.Arrays.copyOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T%3aA-int-). This is what you want:

```
theDirectory = Arrays.copyOf(theDirectory, theDirectory.length * 2);
```