# What exactly is wrong with newarray = oldarray.clone() for md arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

After some search for copying of multidimensional arrays manipulation in java I found this question: [copy a 2d array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686425/copy-a-2d-array-in-java) and a downvoted answer suggests using the method in the title. So my questions are:

**1**) why is it bad? (becuase it looks quick and obvious)

**2**) is the best way still `System.arraycopy` each line?

Comment: because it is **shallow copy** as far as I know

Comment: If you need speed and this really is your main bottleneck, try to avoid multidimensional arrays altogether.

Comment: @biziclop: so if I have, say, m parameters for n individuals instead of an array with N rows and M columns just have a NxM string? How will it help?

Comment: @KickButtowski: could you explain what's wrong with a shallow copy?

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563157/how-to-deep-copy-2-dimensional-array-different-row-sizes 2. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=shallow+copy+vs+deep+copy+java

Comment: @Alex cheack my links

Comment: So the only way to create a deep copy is to loop over every element?

Comment: I still don't see why System.Arraycop() or copyOf() is better than clone() for mn arrays

Comment: @Alex No, don't do that under any circumstances. What I tried to say was that if this **really** is what slows your application down (and 99% of the time it's something else), you might consider using a one-dimensional array with NxM elements.

Comment: @biziclop: no, honestly, my application runs quite fast, but I use array.clone() which seems like an easy way to get a copy of an array. Then I suddenly read (in the question I referred to) that it's a bad idea. So I'm confused now.

Comment: @biziclop:  I mean the last downvoted answer

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, an array is an object. If you have a multidimensional array and you clone it, you won't get copies of the internal arrays (because they are also array `Object`(s)). You could use [`Arrays.copyOf(T[],int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T[],%20int%29). From the linked Javadoc,

> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy but not the original, the copy will contain null. Such indices will exist if and only if the specified length is greater than that of the original array. The resulting array is of exactly the same class as the original array.

**Edit**

The above is analogous to `System.arraycopy()` but *also* creates [**shallow copies**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy). If you need to create [**deep copies**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy) of the multidimensional array you would have to iterate over the array clone and create a deep copy for each row.

Comment: You should clarify that copyOf is also a shallow copy -- whether they use System.arraycopy or copyOf, they need to iterate over the cloned multidimensional array and copy the array in each slot.

Comment: I still don't see why copyOf() or ArrayCopy() are better than clone() for md arrays - if all of them are shallow

Comment: You asked if one was *best*. Technically they're all *best* in that they perform the same function.

Comment: I'm lost: if there's no difference, why bother writing a whole loop over each line instead of one line using clone() if the result is exactly the same?

Comment: @Alex Consider, *what if* your `Object` instances were immutable?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still at loss - what's the advantage of using arraycopy() or copyOf() vs array.clone()