# Java 2D Multiple array initialization

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

In Java, is it possible to initialize several arrays in one line with the same values?

For example, consider this chunk of code

```
double[][] array1 = {
   { 4, 5, 1, 3},
   { 5, 6, 3, 4},
   {10,-1, 45,3},
   { 1, 3, 2, 4}
};
double[][] array2 = {
   { 4, 5, 1, 3},
   { 5, 6, 3, 4},
   {10,-1, 45,3},
   { 1, 3, 2, 4}
}
```

As you can see, both arrays are identical, and they got the same initialization. I wonder if I can declare and assign the same values to both in just one instruction.

I tried:

```
double[][] array1, array2 = {
   { 4, 5, 1, 3},
   { 5, 6, 3, 4},
   {10,-1, 45,3},
   { 1, 3, 2, 4}
};
```

But in the case above, only `array2` is initialized.

EDIT: 
I am looking for independent initialization. The solutions proposed in the possible duplicates questions do not address what I am looking for:

In the case of "[Initializing multiple variables to the same value in Java](http://Initializing%20multiple%20variables%20to%20the%20same%20value%20in%20Java)", the initializations are for Strings, and there, each String has its own initialization (empty string in each case).

In the other possible duplicate "[How to deep copy 2 dimensional array (different row sizes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563157/how-to-deep-copy-2-dimensional-array-different-row-sizes)", it involves an iterative solution, which I already knew, but I am not looking for an iterative solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing multiple variables to the same value in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202818/initializing-multiple-variables-to-the-same-value-in-java)

Comment: Not if you intend to mutate them separately; there's no simple way to deep copy an array.

Comment: If you're intending on them pointing to the same data, you can do something similar with two lines: `double[][] array1, array2; array1 = array2 = <stuff>;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deep copy 2 dimensional array (different row sizes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563157/how-to-deep-copy-2-dimensional-array-different-row-sizes) is done with int[][] but it really doesn't matter. Same thing.

Comment: The solution proposed by phflack is not an actual independent initialization. If you do that and then you change one of the arrays, the other gets changed too. I am not looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double[][] deepCopy(double[][] array) {
    double[][] d = new double[array.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        d[i] = Arrays.copyOf(array[i], array[i].length);
    return d;
}
```